# Variables cant be found by function (R language)

Tags: r, metaprogramming

There's some problem when trying to use new functions to analyse a dataset.
I am trying to plot the relationship between hits and runs in the mlb11 dataset by R language.

The function was as

```
f_plot<-function(x,y,z){
  ggplot(x,aes(y,z))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")
}
```

and if I start to plot like this:

```
f_plot(mlb11,hits, runs)
```

then it will give :

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'hits' not found

Then if I try this:

```
f_plot(mlb11,mlb11$hits, mlb11$runs)
```

It will gives
[this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx49k.png)

This fixed the problem!!
But I am very curious about why the function{} cant read the variable names automatically even if we have already designated the dataset "mlb11"?? Would be appreciated to know more about this basic problem!! Thanks!!

Comment: can you make your example into one which people can run? E.g. make some mock data

Comment: Column "names" are not R object names (aka `symbol`s). When you type `f_plot(mlb11,hits, runs)`, the interpreter is attempting to find objects with those names. The "basic problem" is the use of the word "names" for two quite different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in this line

```
ggplot(x,aes(y,z))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

it's looking for a variable called y and z in the data `x`. The "easiest" way to solve this is to do this

```
f_plot<-function(x,y,z){
  yy <- as.character(substitute(y))
  zz <- as.character(substitute(z))
  code = sprintf('ggplot(x,aes(%s,%s))+geom_point()+geom_smooth(method="lm")', yy, zz)
  #print(code)
  eval(parse(text = code))
}


f_plot(hehe, a, b)
```

this will do the trick but is not the best way to write it. The function `substitute` takes what you passed in to `y` and make it into an expression, which the cocdes converts into a string/text and then put inside the ggplot which then gets evaluated by `eval(parse())`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the helper function `aes()` expects bare variable names as input. This means that when you type `aes(y, z)`, the helper function will not look for the values of the variables "y" and "z" that you supplied to the function `f_plot()`. Instead, it will look for variables called "y" and "z" in the supplied data frame; independently of the values for y and z that were given to `f_plot()`.

To circumvent this behaviour, you can use `aes_()`: this variant doesn't treat its inputs as bare variable names, but instead as variables that refer to a bare variable name in the form of an R expression. For this approach to work, you then only have to convert the "y" and "z" inputs of the function `f_plot()` to R expressions using `substitute()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

f_plot <- function(x, y, z) {
  y <- substitute(y)
  z <- substitute(z)
  ggplot(x, aes_(y, z)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm")
}

df <- data_frame(var1 = 1:10, var2 = 1:10)

f_plot(df, var1, var2)
```

This should make your function work as intended.